# The Normal approximation to the Binomial (I cant find where im going wrong)

Tags: probability, approximation

Here is the main question:

Police estimate that 80% of drivers now wear their seatbelts. They set up a safety roadblock, 
stopping cars to check for seatbelt use
If they stop 20 cars during the first hour, what’s the probability they find at least 18 drivers 
wearing seat belts? Use a 
normal
 distribution to compute your answer

Here is the Answer: = 0.2005

My work:

[image]

I have been following this formula:

u = np (How many times a thing is done * success percent)

Y = npq (How many times a thing is done * success percent * (1 - success percent))

Then -> (what you want to measure) - (u) / sqrt(Y) = final Z-score

As you can see my answer is 0.83 and Ive been trying to figure out where I'm going wrong for a good 2 hours now..

Comment: You have a z score but the question wants a probability.  That’s not the same thing.

Comment: Hm, ok how would I go about getting the answer from what I have?

Comment: The Z score calculated follows a standard normal $N(0,1)$ distribution. Use the fact that $P(Z < z) \sim N(0,1)$ to calculate probabilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have set up the calculation
$$ \frac{17.5 - 16}{\sqrt{3.2}}, $$
which looks like the correct approach to me.

Giving only two digits after the decimal place for a $Z$-score near $0.83$ is not enough precision to give a result accurate to four places, such as the probability $0.2005.$
You should carry more digits in your calculations.

Even if you did not increase the number of digits, you should be more careful how you round. The result should have been closer to $0.84$ than $0.83.$

Once you have a more accurate answer, you can look it up in a table of the normal distribution. 
Note that many such tables require you to add $0.5$ to the result in the table in order to get a probability, and in this case it will give you the probability of $17$ or fewer drivers wearing seatbelts.

I get $0.2009,$ so I suspect that the person writing the answer sheet reported more significant digits than their own methods justified.

Comment: When I look up 8.4 and 1.34 on the table, I get .2995 and .4099 respectively, how did you cut it down to .2009? Did you maybe cut one of them in half? Why so?

Comment: I dont know if this is right but I took the .2995 from 8.4 Z-score, added .5 to make it .7995 then subtracted 1 from the result and it seemed to have got the right answer

Comment: I used a Z score of 8.38525 (which is closer to the exact value). The table entry 0.2995 is for a Z score that is _exactly_ 0.84. The Z score we're looking for is close to 0.84 but not close enough to justify using all four digits after the decimal point. The traditional way to do this is to interpolate between the table values for 0.83 and 0.84; nowadays you can also have software compute the probability. Alternatively, one can just not pretend to have an answer accurate to four digits. If the answer key had said 0.201 I would not complain.

Comment: But anyway the main point is that you got the idea of the correct method now, and 0.2005 is as close to correct as you can get using the usual table without interpolation.